# Internal Speakers not Working

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I have had trouble with these speakers since installing Ubuntu.  I dual-boot Ubuntu with Windows 10.  The speakers are, on the Windows boot, managed by the pre-installed Bang and Olufsen audio manager.  I was able to find out that the speakers were this specific brand of Conexant because I reinstalled ALSA.  I still wasn't able to hear sound from the speakers, and now I can't find anywhere on the computer information on the speakers.  If anyone can help me, that would be perfect!  I appreciate all replies.

EDIT:
After some research, I have stumbled upon a Reddit post, saying that my speakers require a Realtek driver.  My PC is an HP Envy, but not that model.  [Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/hpenvyphoenix/comments/3g7fv6/clean_install_but_cant_find_bo_software/)

Edit2:
After even more research within my Windows partition, I do in fact use a Conexant driver.  Also, it appears that you would need to be able to run the Bang & Olufsen audio manager to run natively on Linux for the audio system to work.

Edit3:
I have done crazy amounts of research and work on this.  I have come to the conclusion that what I had done was add a blacklist to one of the ALSA files that blacklisted my card.  As of now, when I use the program `pavucontrol` I can see the card there.  Sadly, it shows as "(unplugged)".  I am stumped as what to do now.  I have tried many solutions and workarounds from other sites, but still have not been able to crack the case.  I'll post screenshots of what I see from `pavucontrol`.  [Showing Unplugged](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgF9n.png)

Edit5:

I've been trying to fix this for ages, and stumbled upon another peice of info.  It might not help, but the audio device is showing itself as: `00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H HD Audio [8086:a170] (rev 31)`.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Edit6

I have completely reinstalled `Ubuntu 16.10` and my probelem has still not been resolved.  When reinstalling, I wiped my `Windows` partition, so information from there is no longer accessible.  Also, if relevant, I have been using a USB speaker adapter for listening to audio.  I also use a second monitor with my PC, using a HDMI to VGA adapter, with the HDMI part attaching to the primary monitor.  The secondary monitor has no speakers on it.  The model of that monitor is a Dell E196FP.

Comment: Here is the result of running the "alsa-info.sh" script:  http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=1e0db4af6332cf82ee1f2ffa84a0b36f18431247

Comment: New result of running `alsa-info.sh` script running Yakkety 16.10: http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=3d2d39b758a8397e3f861453ffeb9c70bca66d31

Comment: Another user and I are working on a similar problem right now: http://askubuntu.com/questions/854055/switch-between-internal-and-hdmi-speakers-automatically/854079#854079

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Thanks so much for the link!  I'll look into it.