# How to set default speaker to hdmi device? Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: sound, 17.10, alsa, hdmi, speakers

My desktop has a built-in speaker inside the tower, and it's connected to my monitor via HDMI.
It's really annoying that the system defaults the speaker to the built-in one and I have to manually change the Sound settings.
Is there any way to force HDMI as default device or just disable the built-in?

Comment: This might help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/854055/switch-between-internal-and-hdmi-speakers-automatically/854079#854079 If not there are other methods.

Answer (score 1):

To set default for pulseaudio playback

Use command:

```
pactl list sinks | grep Name
```

to get Pulseaudio names of playback sinks

Use the name of your HDMI sink in this command to set it as default:

```
pacmd set-default-sink <Name>
```

To check Pulseaudio default sink setting:

```
cat ~/.config/pulse/*default-sink
```

Comment: I set default sink to the hdmi one, however when I boot up today it still falls back to built in analog audio. Thanks